# Feedholder shape mismatch in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

I get a mismatch of shapes between input and the feedholder even though i am pretty sure that the shapes in both the cases are same. Here's the code:
ex3data1.mat contains a 5000*400 matrix X.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
   `import scipy.io as sio
    theta1 = sio.loadmat('ex3weights.mat')['Theta1']
    theta2 = sio.loadmat('ex3weights.mat')['Theta2']
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[1, 400])
    x2 = tf.concat([[[1]] ,x], 1)
    z2 = tf.matmul(x2,np.transpose(theta1))
    h1 = tf.divide(1.0, (1.0 + tf.exp(-z1)))
    h1= tf.concat([[[1]],h1], 1)
    z2 = tf.matmul(h1, np.transpose(theta2))
    max = tf.argmax(z2)
    max = max+1 
    sess = tf.Session()
    op = sio.loadmat('ex3data1.mat')['X'][1234]
    op = np.reshape(op, [1, 400])
    op.astype(np.float64)
    m = {x:op}
    sess.run(max,feed_dict=m)
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype double and shape [1,400]
     [[Node: Placeholder_2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_DOUBLE, shape=[1,400], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but `op.astype(np.float64)` does nothing.  `astype` is not an inplace operation - actually that might be the error.  The message says the dtype must match as well as the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you

```
print(op.shape)
```

before assigning the dict to m? I suppose this is [5000, 400]. Reshape works when the number of elements does not change. But in case when you expect 'input_width' wide stream, you may define a placeholder this way:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, input_width], "network_input")
```

allowing the numer of cases to be flexible. Then you can feed it with any number of cases, like 5000 and the math will still work.